# Split column data from CSV - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, append

I have CSVs with the sample data as follows:

[image: Table]

The column headers remain the same for all the data in other CSVs. I need to separate out the "Animal" column from all the CSVs and then perform edit(append) operation on "Animal" data (one CSV per run of the script). The "Animal" column is at position=3 for this sample but the position differs for other CSVs.
I have written the following code:

```
 csv_name = input('Enter the filename: ')
 file_name = "%s.csv" %csv_name

 csv_file = open (file_name).read().splitlines()
 for row in csv_file:
    k=(row.split(','))
    if 'Animal' in k:
            position_column = k.index('Animal')
    print(row[position_column])
```

I'm not sure what delimiter to be used as `comma` isn't working for split operation. Any other way to do this?

**NOTE: I cannot use other modules or any libraries like CSV Module, Pandas, Numpy, RegEx etc. to perform operations on the CSV.**

Comment: Maybe you should try to get the other libraries to work instead of reinventing the wheel?

Comment: The issue here is, the `Place` column contains commas. It should also be enclosed in quotes to signal this. So you would need to parse the row to detect this rather than just using `split()`. This is what the other libraries do.

Comment: I'm not sure where would I need the additional quotes. I understood the issue with the `Place` column though